# how to configure ng-admin to work with several different URIs

Tags: javascript, ng-admin

how can I configure `ng-admin` to work with several different URI endpoints?
e.g.

```
var admin = nga.application('My Admin')
.baseApiUrl('http://localhost:6007/api/v1/');
```

lets me use `localhost:6007` as my URI
I would like to be able to use additional URIs for other entities
(service oriented architecture - not all entities are coming from the same URI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be configured on entity as well -

```
var entity = nga.entity('entity').baseURL('http://localhost:6007/api/v1/');
```